# Потеря данных при отправке двумерного массива объектов - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы, express

Есть объект карты:

```
var map = {
    grid: [],
    tileSize: 40,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    dest: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
```

Где `grid` - это двумерный массив, эл-ми которого являются объекты (до 20 полей, без методов) или 0:

```
[{…}, {…}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {…}, {…}]
[{…}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {…}]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[{…}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {…}]
[{…}, {…}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {…}, {…}]
```

Отправляется через `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/saveMap/name=' + name,
            type: 'POST',
            //cache: false,
            data: map,
            success: function () {
                console.log(map);
                dataMan.updateMaps();
                map.update();
            }
        });
```

На серверной стороне для обработки запросов используется `express`:

```
router.post('/saveMap/name=:name', (req, res, next)=>{
    let name = req.params.name;
    data = req.body;
    for(a in data.grid)
        console.log(data.grid[a].length)

    maps[name] = data;
    fs.writeFileSync('data/maps.json', JSON.stringify(maps), ()=>{return true});
    res.status(200).send()
});
```

При получении, длины строк разнятся: к примеру у первой и последней длина 9, до этого пробовал отправлять объект, в котором map был лишь одним из полей - обрезалась последняя колонка (это было видно как по длине, так и по записанным в файл данным). В чём может быть причина такого поведения и как это исправить?
P.S.: пример объекта:

```
Rock = {
    "width":"1",
    "height":"1",
    "god":"1",
    "health":"1",
    "img":"1544355440178.jpg",
    "collision":"1"
}
```

Comment: Поставьте точку остановки на сервере и посмотрите, что у вас приходит в `data.grid`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko сейчас первые две строки 9, последняя 8 (при массиве 10*10), причём обрезались как 0, так и один из объектов

Comment: Вы это в дебагере видите или в консоли?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дебаггер

Comment: Что-то очень странное получается. Попробуйте отправить массив 10*10 заполненный всему нулями. Также посмотрите во вкладке Networks в браузере и удостоверьтесь, что отправляете действительно правильные данные.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, данные отправляются корректные. Но если массив заполнен 0, то проблемы нет, но всё-равно не совсем понятно почему при наличии объектов в строке, она обрезается

Comment: Возможно, у вас есть еще какие-то обработчики до `/saveMap/name=:name`, которые могут модифицировать данные. Еще думал вариант про ограничения размера для POST, но в таком случае у вас был бы не валидный JSON.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko обработчиков точно нет, попробую с разными объектами поэксперементировать